# Find all small integer triples that solve $a^x + b^x - c^x = 0$

Tags: mathematics

Consider the equation

$$a^x + b^x - c^x = 0.$$

List all integer triples $(a, b, c)$ where each of $a, b, c$ has absolute value at most 10 for which there exists a real valued solution to that equation.

To start things off, (0, 0, 0) is one such triple.

Comment: Hm, interesting. It's easy for non-negative a, b, c. But I'm not sure yet how to handle negatives.

Comment: @justhalf could you add the solutions you do have to an answer? I would be interested to see them.

Comment: I come to 868 solutions. A bit long to ask a list of. (<= suggestion for if you ever ask a similar question that is more on topic for this site)

Comment: @Retudin do you have solutions that are not covered by the existing answers? How did you do it?

Comment: Yes. the most obvious one is that 0<c<b and 0<c<a always yields a solution, reasoning is like the second answer but using negative values of x. There are also many simple x=1 answers like {5,-3,2 }  (but you question is closed)

Answer (score 2):

Partial answer, as requested by OP in comments. Here I only answer for non-negative a, b, c.

Rearranging, we have:
$$\sqrt[x]{a^x+b^x} = c$$

Let $f_{a,b}(x) = \sqrt[x]{a^x+b^x}$. So we want $f$ to equal to some integer not greater than 10.

This function of $x$ is continuous, with image $(\max(a,b), \infty)$ (the infimum of $f$ as $x\rightarrow\infty$ is $\max(a,b)$, and goes to $\infty$ as $x\rightarrow 0$) and when we have either $a=0$ or $b=0$, we have $f_{a,b}(x)$ equal to the other value. So, an integer $c$ will have a solution $x$ if and only if $c$ is greater than $\max(a,b)$. So the solution set for non-negative a, b, c is:

> $(0,n,n)$ for $0\leq n \leq 10$
>  $(n,0,n)$ for $0\leq n \leq 10$
>  $(a,b,c)$ for $1\leq a,b \leq 9$ and $c \geq \max(a,b)+1$

This argument doesn't work directly when a, b, c can be negative, as $f$ is not continuous in the real domain in that case, since it will have imaginary component. It has no imaginary component only for some values of $x$. Additional work is required to make this argument work for negative a, b, c as well, which I haven't had the time to think about yet.

Some graph to visualize $f$:

> [image: The plot of f for a=1, b=2]
>  The plot of $f_{1,2}(x)$, for $0\leq x \leq 10$

Comment: This doesn't seem to cover (4, 6, 9) does it?

Comment: It does. It covers (4,6,7), (4,6,8), (4,6,9), and (4,6,10). Oh, I see my mistake. Editing

Comment: Oh that's cool! You snuck in just before the question was closed too

Comment: Well, I guess the closing is justified, haha. Cool question tho.

Comment: You have the case for when c is the largest of the (non-negative) triplet, but the same works for when c is the smallest of the (positive) triplet, because then 1/c is larger than 1/a and 1/b, and there is a negative x that makes the expression zero.

Comment: @JaapScherphuis good point!

Answer (score 1):

Very far from exhaustive, just some solutions:

> $(0,b,b)$ for $\lvert b \rvert \le 10$ and any $x$
>  $(a,-a,0)$ for $\lvert a \rvert \le 10$ and any odd integer $x$
>  $(p,p,2p)$ for $\lvert p \rvert \le 5$ and $x=1$
>  $(1,4,9)$ for $x=1/2$
>  $(1,1,8)$ for $x=1/3$
>  $(3,4,5)$ for $x=2$
>  $(2p,2p,p)$ for $1 \le \lvert p \rvert \le 5$ and $x=-1$
>  $(3,6,2)$ for $x=-1$

Another small remark :

> Any solution triplet $(a,b,c)$ can produce another one: $(-a,-b,-c)$.

Comment: There are more solutions with $a=2$ and $a=4$.

Comment: Also with $a=1$ and $a=3$.